# Shared libraries not found but in ld.so.conf path

Tags: linux

I am trying to install Cracklib 2.9.6 from source so that I can build Shadow against it, but I am running into a problem when trying to build the dictionaries and install them.

```
/sources/cracklib-2.9.6$ create-cracklib-dict /usr/share/dict/cracklib-words \
/usr/share/dict/cracklib-extra-words
cracklib-packer: error while loading shared libraries: libcrack.so.2:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The shared libraries are installed in /lib:

```
/sources/cracklib-2.9.6$ ls /lib/libcrack*
/lib/libcrack.so.2  /lib/libcrack.so.2.9.0
```

There are symbolic links in /usr/lib to the real libraries in /lib:

```
/sources/cracklib-2.9.6$ ls -al /usr/lib/libcrack*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 913 Jul 17 22:06 /usr/lib/libcrack.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Jul 17 22:06 /usr/lib/libcrack.so -> ../../lib    /libcrack.so.2.9.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Jul 17 22:28 /usr/lib/libcrack.so.2 -> ../../lib/libcrack.so.2
```

The last symbolic link is one I created myself to try and solve this problem, in case create-cracklib-dict was only looking in /usr/lib for the shared library. I do not know why create-cracklib-dict is not finding them. I have used a similar install method for several other libraries compiled from source and have had no issues.

EDIT: I am now having the same problem with bunzip2. If I use `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libbz2.so.1.0 /bin/bunzip2`, then the program works. Here's my /etc/ld.so.conf:

```
# Begin /etc/ld.so.conf
/usr/local/lib
/opt/lib
/lib

# Add an include directory
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Running `ldd -p` shows that the /lib directory is within the path searched by ld. Here is the output from `ldconfig -v`

```
/sources/XML-Parser-2.44$ cat ldconfig.log
/usr/local/lib:
/lib:
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.23.so
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.23.so
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.23.so
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.23.so
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.23.so
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.23.so
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.23.so
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.23.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.23.so
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.23.so
    ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.23.so
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.23.so
    libncursesw.so.6 -> libncursesw.so.6.0
    libnss_db.so.2 -> libnss_db-2.23.so
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.23.so
    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.25
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.23.so
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.23.so
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libprocps.so.5 -> libprocps.so.5.0.0
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.23.so
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libcrack.so.2 -> libcrack.so.2.9.0
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.6
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.23.so
    libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.3
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.23.so
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
/usr/lib:
    libssp.so.0 -> libssp.so.0.0.0
    libubsan.so.0 -> libubsan.so.0.0.0
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    libmpfr.so.4 -> libmpfr.so.4.1.3
    libltdl.so.7 -> libltdl.so.7.3.1
    libgdbm.so.4 -> libgdbm.so.4.0.0
    libmenuw.so.6 -> libmenuw.so.6.0
    libformw.so.6 -> libformw.so.6.0
    libasan.so.2 -> libasan.so.2.0.0
    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
    libquadmath.so.0 -> libquadmath.so.0.0.0
    libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.3.0
    libgdbm_compat.so.4 -> libgdbm_compat.so.4.0.0
    libfl.so.2 -> libfl.so.2.0.0
    libitm.so.1 -> libitm.so.1.0.0
    libopcodes-2.26.20160125.so -> libopcodes.so
    libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1 -> libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1.0.0
    libcilkrts.so.5 -> libcilkrts.so.5.0.0
    libatomic.so.1 -> libatomic.so.1.1.0
    libgmpxx.so.4 -> libgmpxx.so.4.5.0
    libvtv.so.0 -> libvtv.so.0.0.0
    libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
    libcc1.so.0 -> libcc1.so.0.0.0
    libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
    libbfd-2.26.20160125.so -> libbfd.so
    libmpc.so.3 -> libmpc.so.3.0.0
    libgomp.so.1 -> libgomp.so.1.0.0
    libfl_pic.so.2 -> libfl_pic.so.2.0.0
    libpanelw.so.6 -> libpanelw.so.6.0
```

Something interesting happened when I invoked `ldconfig -v` though, I got the following message:

```
/sources/XML-Parser-2.44$ ldconfig -v > ldconfig.log
ldconfig: Path `/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
```

Running `ldd -d -r /bin/bunzip2` results in the following:

```
/sources/XML-Parser-2.44$ ldd -d -r /bin/bunzip2
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xb77bc000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7608000)
    /tools/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77bd000)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzlibVersion  (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzReadClose   (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzWriteOpen   (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzWrite   (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzReadGetUnused   (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzWriteClose64    (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzReadOpen    (/bin/bunzip2)
undefined symbol: BZ2_bzRead    (/bin/bunzip2)
```

Comment: Very well asked for somebody new here. Actually enough info to get help. That's refreshing.

Comment: Can you post the output of: `ldd -d -r` on the create-cracklib-dict executable?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of `file -L /usr/lib/libcrack.so.2`?

Comment: Added. I'm not sure why it's still referencing /tools/lib/libc.so.6 and /tools/lib/ld-linux.so.2 when it should be pointing to the /lib versions of those libraries. This is a good clue, but I'm still not sure why that's happening.

Comment: `$ file -L /usr/lib/libcrack.so.2
/usr/lib/libcrack.so.2: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`

Comment: I have confirmed that compiling a dummy.c with the gcc I built on this system also uses the /tools/lib/libc.so.6. I'm going to try rebuilding gcc to see if that clears this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being an issue with my compiler-linker toolchain. The specs file gcc was using to compile all the libraries in question was pointing to an older version of ld located in the /tools/ directory. Readjusting the specs file per the instructions [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/adjusting.html) resulted in gcc producing binaries that compiled against the correct linker and called on the correct dynamic library loader that was able to search /lib and /usr/lib and find the libraries. In other words, be **very** careful when adjusting the gcc specs file!

Answer (score 1):

After placing new files into the ld.so search path, you must run `ldconfig` to update the cache.

See the ldconfig manpage for the reference: http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig

Comment: I've run ldconfig so many times I can type it with my eyes shut. No effect.